# Find out which row is sorted and if it is ascending or descending

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a created custom table header by extending `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer`

```
public class TableHeaderRenderer extends DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;

    public TableHeaderRenderer()
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel(" ");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(label);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        label.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, (column == 0 ? 1 : 0), 1, 1, Color.Red));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to show the little up or down arrow for the column that is sorted that is being displayed in so many other tables.
I have tried searching to figure out which column is sorted and in which order, but they yielded no results.

Can anyone suggest how I may go about doing that?

Comment: Try [`JTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateRowSorter-boolean-).  If that doesn't work for you, try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: 1. agree with an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with harcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable, 2. RowSorter can returns (for concrete column) ACS..., DECS..., UNSORTED

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do have it set to true, however the arrow is not being displayed. I mean how can it? I have to do it myself within the renderer class. I am doing `table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableHeaderRenderer());` and this will defult to my renderer which does not show the arrow. I will try to post MCVE or SSCCE, however I do not know how well I can restrict it to a small sample since the code will be rather large with multiple classes, due to the fact that I have to create JFrame, JTable, assign header, etc...

Comment: to show the little up or down arrow for the column that is sorted that is being displayed in so many other tables. == Icon, more value is in UIManager

Comment: *"..the code will be rather large"*  Remove irrelevant code.  It ain't rocket science. *"..with multiple classes, due to the fact that I have to create JFrame, JTable, assign header, etc.."*  I see exactly one class there, 2 if you count the custom header.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have to give you the sorter that's one class. I have to give another class for creation of jframe and jtable. And I will have to give another class for table model. But I will try.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am sorry but I highly doubt that what you request is relevant to trying to solve the question. I will wait for someone else to help me. Thanks for your help, but I do not think you grasp what I am asking or how custom header renderers work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the arrows to show up via doing the following.

I replaced

```
label_.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

with

```
if (table.getRowSorter() != null && table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys() != null && !table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().isEmpty() &&
        table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().get(0).getColumn() == column)
{
    if (table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING)
    {
        label_.setText(String.valueOf(value) + "  \u25b2");
    }
    else if (table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.DESCENDING)
    {
        label_.setText(String.valueOf(value) + "  \u25bc");
    }
}
else
{
    label_.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}
```

And the arrows show up as they should.

Comment: 1. there is an easier, direct way, you still have to ( I will wait for someone else to help me. )  2. this code missing, there isn't mentiones about UNSORTED :-), 3. again why is hardcoded, put as key to the UIManager, then is visible, acceptable in (e.g.) Nimbus L&F too